# SQL SERVER - Need help. I understand you can do isnull , but is there is "notNull?

Tags: sql-server

```
set DisplayName = concat(Title, ' ', FirstName, ' ', substring(MiddleName), 0, 2), '. ', LastName, ' ', Suffix)
```

So, there are names with out a suffix (Title, and names with out the middle name, so no middle initial. 
I want it so when it sets Display name, if it has a Tittle and a middle name than provide the space and the period for the middle name. Right now its included null as a blank space, so right now I will get an extra blank space if there is no title,and a period/space if there is no middle initial; I only want it when the values for Middlename and Title are NOT null

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard trick:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(ISNULL('Title' + ' ', ''), 'FirstName', ' ', ISNULL(SUBSTRING('MiddleName', 1, 2) + '. ', ''), 'LastName', ' ', 'Suffix')
SELECT  CONCAT(ISNULL(NULL + ' ', ''), 'FirstName', ' ', ISNULL(NULL + '. ', ''), 'LastName', ' ', 'Suffix')
```

Outputs:

```
Title FirstName Mi. LastName Suffix
FirstName LastName Suffix
```

To apply to your example:

```
SET DisplayName = CONCAT(ISNULL(Title + ' ', ''), 
                         FirstName, 
                         ' ', 
                         ISNULL(SUBSTRING(MiddleName, 0, 2) + '. ', ''),
                         LastName, 
                         ' ', 
                         Suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET displayname = concat(title+' '
, firstname, ' '
, substring(middlename, 0, 2) + '. '
, lastname
, ' ' + suffix)
```

So what we are doing here is we are using a `'+' operator` instead of `CONCAT`. The difference is if a `NULL` is concatenated using `'+' operator` it will return a `NULL` as a result. So if a space will be concatenated with a `NULL` result, say middle name, the whole thing will become `NULL` and no blank space will be shown.

Comment: It wasn't giving me a syntax error. It was just giving me what I didn't want, but it was working.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra:- Check the closing paranthesis  :)

Comment: @JoeValenti Can you please tell me what exactly do you want, with an example, maybe? I might be able to help. :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi haha, I almost started doubting all the SQL I knew

Comment: Actually, this is better then mine, because `concat` automatically ignores nulls. I have redundant `ISNULL` function used in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you create DisplayName only for user interface, then I think you can do it in your buisness layer - not sql query

Put all results of sql query in the array or list. Then concatenate only not empty string with empty space between them
For example C# code approach which can be used in others .NET Framework languages

```cs
string[] names = {Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix}
string DisplayName = string.Join(" ", names.Where((value) => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) == false);
```

Comment: Please add in the code example, what language you are using.